# Centroids of a region

Tags: calculus, centroid

Sketch the region bounded on the left by $x=1$, bounded above by $y=\frac{1}{x^3}$, and bounded below by $y=-\frac{1}{x^3}$.

a) find the centroid of the region for $1 \leq x \leq 6$

b) find the centroid of the region for $1 \leq x \leq  b$

c) Where is the centroid as $ b\to \infty$

I have calculated part a to be (48/13, 0) but I cannot get past part b

Comment: Welcome at MSE. It is common on MSE that users show what they have tried, so that other can help them solving the problem. You should also learn how to use Mathjax so your typsetting is easier to read. This will also enhance your chance that someone is answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A=\int_{1}^{b}2ydx=\int_{1}^{b}\frac{2}{x^3}dx=1-\frac{1}{b^2}$$
when the $b=6$
$$A=1-\frac{1}{36}=\frac{35}{36}$$

now we will calculate the moment about y-axis to find the x center 
$$M_y=\int_{1}^{b}2y(x-1)dx=\int_{1}^{b}\frac{2}{x^3}(x-1)dx=\frac{1-2b}{b^2}+1$$
when $b=6$
$$M_y=\frac{25}{36}$$

$$x_c=\frac{M_y}{A}=(25/36)/(35/36)=\frac{25}{36}=\frac{5}{7}$$
then you can conclude the answer when the $b=infinity$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Due to symmetry about the x-axis of the region bounded above by the curve $y=\frac{1}{x^3}$, below by the curve $y=\frac{-1}{x^3}$ & on the left of the line $x=1$ , the centroid of the bounded region will lie on the x-axis at some point $(\bar{x}, 0)$ given as $$\bar{x}=\frac{\int xdA}{\int dA}$$

Where, $dA=\text{area of the bounded region}=\int ydx$, hence we get 
$$\bar{x}=\frac{\int xydx}{\int y dx}$$